# Xcode 8 - Swift 3 - Break my app

Tags: ios, xcode, swift3

On the previous version of xcode ( Xcode 8 beta 6 ) , my app running fine without errors. I updated xcode this morning, I run my app and now, I have 400 errors ! 
Pods installed not working and on my code all is on red !

I'm a bit frustrated to have made an update and this has resulted to demolish my application.

How can I resolve my situation ?

Example of code not working now :

```
if UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "token") != nil => Use of unresolved identifier 

 if( CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() == CLAuthorizationStatus.authorizedWhenInUse => Type CLAuthorizationStatus has no member authorizedWhenInUse
```

No luck, I had to quickly add an update that corrects a version of the app store that crash at startup ...

Answer (score 0):

The newest version of Xcode, Xcode 8 beta or Xcode 8 GM seed, runs on an updated and swifter version of Swift. Likely your errors are because your command strings are now too long. If you cannot convert the files, you may need to go in and edit each command line. Refer to the release notes for the newest version of Xcode you have to find these new statements.

Example:

```
// old code (Swift 2.2)
let content = text.stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet(NSCharacterSet.newlineCharacterSet())

// new code (Swift 3.0)
let content2 = text.trimmingCharacters(in: .newlines)
```

resource:
https://developer.apple.com/swift/